# Change path/url of admin-bar.min.css

Tags: urls, admin-bar, wp-register-style

Does anyone know where admin-bar.min.css is registeded/included?

Im trying to add a slash in front of admin-bar.min.css, so the admin bar will work correctly on all pages. Im playing arround with a wordpress site with dynamicaly generated urls, and right now the admin bar is the last thing I need to fix, only I cant find it.

All help is much apriciated :)

Comment: which version of wordpress you are using. I dint seen any reference to admin-bar.min.css in wordpress 3.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`admin-bar.min.css` is not registered via the normal `wp_register_style` channels. It, and the other default styles, are registered by [`wp_default_styles`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L513), which registers them by directly manipulation the `$styles` object, though I don't know what good that is since there are no hooks and you shouldn't be hacking core files.

You should still be able to [deregister that style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) and re-add it. If that doesn't work I expect that you'd need to alter the `$styles` object yourself.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me find what I was looking for :) saved me a bunch of time.

Comment: `grep` is my very best friend.